# Find Condition on the matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ where $m\leq n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find condition on the matrix X so that the expression $X^TAXB$ is a symmetric matrix where $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $B$ is an arbitrary matrix and $X$ is a non-square matrix. Here $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$.

Comment: I couldn't find such X, I want to find such X or want some necessary and sufficient condition under which such X exists.

Comment: Well, I haven't really looked into this, but making $X$ the zero matrix would make the product symmetric. That's the one easy solution I could think of.

Comment: U need to find a non-zero X or more precisely I need to find a full column rank matrix X. Please have a look into the problem. I need your helpful suggestion.